# conflict in httpclient4.1.jar and httpclient4.2.3.jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

in line 2 below:

when i use httpclient4.1.jar in my libs setRedirectStrategy error removed and laxRedirect error occured (and laxRedirect import also take error)-error(1) below,

when i use httpclient4.2.3, laxredirect error removed and setRedirectStrategy error occured- error(2) below .

what i do? (use 4.1 or 4.2.3, and what chages must be done?)

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
```

imports are:

```
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.LaxRedirectStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

and errors are:

```
1- The method setRedirectStrategy(LaxRedirectStrategy) is undefined for the type DefaultHttpClient

2- LaxRedirectStrategy cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RedirectStrategy` was introduced with [4.1](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#setRedirectStrategy%28org.apache.http.client.RedirectStrategy%29) and is now deprecated.So when you included 4.1 jar `setRedirectStrategy` worked but with 4.2.3 it didn't.

In this case you can't override the system (Android's) implementation.So from here i would suggest you to refer SO questions [No. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255150/android-app-not-recognizing-setredirectstrategy),[No. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352949/preventing-httpclient-4-from-following-redirect) and [No. 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821742/how-to-set-redirect-strategy-in-apache-async-http-client).

Comment: I check it, but it suggest to import "org.apache.http.impl.client.LaxRedirectStrategy" again.

Comment: error: "The import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.LaxRedirectStrategy cannot be resolved"

Comment: Sorry to say `setRedirectStrategy` is deprecated after 4.1.See my edited answer.